# How to escape % symbol in Where statement

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

How do i escape the '%' in the sense that i want to remove any statements with the '%' symbol in it.

The following code is an example `->where('dst', 'not like', '%#%')` in Laravel Eloquent, where the strings matching anything with a '#' is removed.

I want to do the same for '%' where any strings with % in the string like %4214231%423 is removed from the query result.

Comment: Can you post the code of what you already tried?

Comment: So essentially i am trying to do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE dst NOT LIKE '% % %' where any string that has the % symbol anywhere in the string is removed. I can do the NOT LIKE command for #s and *s but i can't remove % symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you should do is to add '\' before percent sign.

```
->where('dst', 'not like', '%\%%')
```